# AngularJS no me representa las variables del controlador en la vista, salen vacías

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-injector

Tengo este código javascript en un script llamado indexController.js y el html en un index.html, el problema está en que la variable "mensaje" no la está pintando en la pantalla.

¿Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal? Estoy muy acostumbrado a Angular pero acabo de comenzar con AngularJS puesto que tengo un proyecto que entregar a cliente y lo quiere en esta tecnología.

Un saludo.

```js
angular.module('holamundo', [])
        .controller('miControlador', miControlador);

    function miControlador(){
        var scope = this;
        scope.mensaje = "Hola, ¿Como estas?";

        console.log(scope);

        init();

        function init(){
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="holamundo" ng-controller="miControlador">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Angular JS - Hola Mundo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./indexController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        {{mensaje}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función que registras como controlador tiene que recibir un parámetro
con el nombre *$scope*, luego con este se puede modificar el contexto.
Por ejemplo:

```
angular.module('holamundo', [])
       .controller('miControlador', miControlador);

function miControlador($scope){
    $scope.mensaje = "Hola, ¿Como estas?";
}
```

Si quieres puedes seguir usando tu código pero para que funcione tienes
que cambiar un par de cosas en el html.

En

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="holamundo" ng-controller="miControlador">
```

El *ng-controller* de "miControlador" a "miControlador as mc".

Luego tienes que referirte a *mensaje* como *mc.mensaje*:

```
<body>
    <div>
        {{mc.mensaje}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Entonces una pregunta, porque aqui los declara así: https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/controladores-controller-angularjs.html
https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/ejercicio-controladores-angularjs.html

Comment: Ahí edite mi respuesta con la información de ese tutorial